# Is it possible to get information as byte (or text( variable in the WiFi?

Tags: c#, c++, passwords, wifi, lan

Is it possible to receive all bytes which are flowing in WiFi? Can I receive it as a byte or text using (if I know the WiFi passowrd)? The programing language isn't importatant for me. I think that everybody can read the informations which are flowing using the WiFi because they're the electromagnic waves?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That's how WiFi works.

Comment: Study `Sockets` and `Socket Programming`!

Comment: But how can I do it? Is it necessary to write a own driver to the WiFi adapter?

Comment: google network sniffer

Comment: A Web Connection uses TCP as the Transport Layer so you can connect using TCP.

Comment: @Pawelsar1: If you wanna eavesdrop on the packets, then no, you can listen to the network adapter using sockets. If you wanna communicate with the WiFi from your code, again no need to write a driver, you communicate to the adapter using sockets again. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: @jdweng: It can also use UDP, for example when it comes to Streaming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark (www.wireshark.org) to decode packets that are flowing in or out of the machine the programme is running on.

To snoop on packets that are passing between other machines you'll need something that can capture raw packets, such as Shark for Root for Android (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&hl=en)

Of course, if the traffic is encrypted (connected to an HTTPS address or through a VPN for example) then it's a lot more difficult to decode (though the NSA doesn't have much trouble). You'll need to become a "man in the middle" or get hold of the encryption keys somehow.

Comment: Fiddler from Telerik is potentially better than Wireshark.

Comment: I know that I can use programs, but I want to know how do they work?

Comment: @Pawelsar1: All of them use Sockets as I said, you create a socket and using appropriate arguments you can sniff the traffic. If you use C#, then `System.Net.Socket`. Or take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank. But is sniffing the data possible without dynamically changing the MAC and/or local IP?